# Azure Resource Manager Template Set VM Time Zone

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have used this

```
"osProfile": {
    "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vmNamePrefix'), copyIndex(1))]",
    "adminUsername": "[parameters('vmAdminUsername')]",
    "adminPassword": "[parameters('vmAdminPassword')]",
    "windowsConfiguration": {
        "timeZone": "GMT Standard Time"
    }
}
```

To Try and set the time zone when deploying a new VM but I keep getting this deployment error: The value of parameter windowsConfiguration.timeZone is invalid.

The syntax seems to be correct as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines but it looks like it doesn't like the `GMT Standard Time` bit.

Any idea what sort of value needs to go here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this powershell expression:

```
[System.TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones() | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
```

Comment: If you want your current local timezone id only then use `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local|select -ExpandProperty Id`.